# Why is my case table selection not pointing to the correct address after I enter the lookup value?

Tags: assembly, irvine32

For a programming exercise in Assembly Language for x86 Processors, I created a case table selection program in Visual Studio that would take in an integer value and point to the respected procedure associated with that value. However, when I enter in an integer, it doesn't point to the correct procedure. In fact, it completely bypasses the selection process.

When I run the program and enter in an integer between 1-4, it doesn't display anything and ends the program.

Note: I'm new to assembly language so I don't know too much.

```
INCLUDE irvine32.inc

.data
CaseTable  BYTE  '1'
       DWORD AND_op
       BYTE  '2'
       DWORD OR_op
       BYTE '3'
       DWORD NOT_op         
       BYTE '4'
       DWORD XOR_op
    NumberOfEntries = 4

    titlemsg BYTE "---------- Boolean Calculator ----------", 0
    ANDprompt BYTE "1.  X AND Y", 0
    ORprompt BYTE "2.  X OR Y", 0
    NOTprompt BYTE "3.  NOT X", 0
    XORprompt BYTE "4.  X XOR Y", 0
    Exitprompt BYTE "5.  Exit Program", 0
    askUser BYTE "Please enter an option number: ", 0

.code
main PROC
    ; Display prompts and title...


    mov edx, OFFSET askUser
    Call WriteString
    Call ReadInt        ; Inserts number entered into the EAX register

    .IF al == 5    ; Conditional Statement if user chooses to end program.
        jmp L3
    .ENDIF

    mov ebx, OFFSET CaseTable
    mov ecx, NumberOfEntries

L1:
    cmp al, [ebx]           ; Match found?
    jne L2              ; No: Continue
    Call NEAR PTR [ebx + 1]     ; Yes: Call procedure

    Call Crlf
    jmp L3
L2:
    add ebx, 5
    loop L1
L3:

    INVOKE ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
; Procedures called after a match has been made merely display text to the screen, so they are unimportant to the problem at hand.
END main
```

Comment: You used `ReadInt` which returns an integer not a character. As such your table should contain integers not characters. E.g. replace `'1'` with just `1`. Also, learn to use the debugger.

Comment: I have used the debugger, it's how I watched the registers and found that it skipped the `Call NEAR PTR [ebx + 1]` part of the code. Once it compares the AL register with [EBX], it jumps.

Comment: In addition, even when I change the lookup values within the table to integers, it still doesn't locate the correct procedure.

Comment: Use the debugger at the `cmp al, [ebx]` and verify `al=1` and that `[ebx]` is also `1`. If those are true, the `jne` must not jump and the `call` can not be skipped.

Comment: Use your debugger to 1) read value of ebx 2) read a byte of memory at that address

Comment: Just solved the issue. Thanks Jester! Turns out the I did need to take out the quotation marks to have `cmp al, [ebx]` function properly. Thank you for your assistance!